# Z-index not working on fixed header and fixed drop down menu

Tags: css, z-index

I am trying to design a fixed drop down menu that slides and then sits under a fixed header for my website when it's being viewed by smaller view ports. I must not be understanding something correctly because despite setting position properly and using a z-index *lower* than its parent on the nav, it still does not work correctly. On drop down it slides under the menu button I have created, but over the header and then stays above the header. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="menu-button" class="up">menu</div>
    <nav role="primary" class="hide">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">foobar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">foobar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">foobar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">foobar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">foobar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">foobar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #222;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
#menu-button {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 1);
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #222;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: .25em .5em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.up {
    background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .2), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .2));
}
.down {
    background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .2), hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .2));
}
nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease;
}
.hide ul {
    top: -500px;
}
.reveal ul {
    top: 50px;
}
nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 35%, 1);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    transition: .4s all;
    -webkit-transition: .4s all;
    -moz-transition: .4s all;
    -o-transition: .4s all;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(even) a {
    border-right: none;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 1);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menu-button').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('down');
    $('nav').toggleClass('reveal');
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle I made for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/kyleshevlin/yaJyK/6/

Comment: The problem is that a child cannot override its parent's `z-index`. As a result you can have to change your HTML markup some, as dc5 suggested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this and keep your fixed header requirement is to add a wrapper around the menu button:

```
<div class='menu-wrap'>
    <div id="menu-button" class="up">menu</div>
</div>
<nav role="primary" class="hide">
    …
</nav>
```

Make the menu wrapper the full width/height of the menubar:

```
.menu-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: blue; /* just to make it obvious… */
}
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaJyK/11/)

Comment: Thanks dc5 that seems to do everything I want it to do. I would like to know how you thought to do this. It doesn't seem intuitive, but I'm finding out that not everything in coding is intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have the menu (that you want with a lower z-index) inside the fixed element (which has a bigger z-index).
You have to separate those two, make both of them fixed and put your content below in an absolute positionned container with a top = header height (or a margin-top)

Then both the header and the menu will stay in place, and you can set each z-index independently ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/yaJyK/13/))

```
header {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #222;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index:1;
}
nav{
    position:fixed;
    transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease;
    width:100%;
}

<header>
    <div id="menu-button" class="up">menu</div>
</header>
<nav role="primary" class="hide">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">foobar</a></li>
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Your fiddle still has the text on top of the menu, but understanding that I can't override the parent z-index helps me understand why my project wasn't working.

Comment: yes, just increase the `z-index` of both the header and the menu and it's done.
http://jsfiddle.net/yaJyK/14/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the z-index on the parent(header) and add a position:relative.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why that would work. But just in case I'm missing something, I tried it in his fiddle. It didn't seem to work. Perhaps more explanation would be helpful?

Comment: That works. I'm not the OP, but I'd be very interested if you could add an explanation. Or at least a link to some relevant documentation.

Comment: @lansen, while that works (and I actually noticed changing the fixed positioning did that before I posted), I need the header to stay at the top of the page so that you can scroll the rest of the page underneath it. Position relative would allow the header to scroll away. EDIT: Just noticed you have two positions. Wouldn't the fixed one cancel the relative since CSS reads the rules backwards?

Comment: @lansen, I also chose to add some dummy text to your fiddle, and the header doesn't stay fixed and the text now sits on top of the menu Thus, i need to be able to give the menu a positive z-index that is still lower than the header so it sits above the text but below the header.

Answer (score 0):

I had an *inner* `<div>` and an *outer* `<div>`.

My *inner div's* `z-index` was not working because the *outer div* did not have a `z-index` defined.

```css
.inner {z-index:999}
.outer {z-index:111} /*<-- explicitly defined*/
```